# preg_match UTF-8 problems unknown symbols instead of Cyrillic

Tags: regex, utf-8, preg-match

my script work great, but today after checkin logs i found some matrix words, after analysing i understood that there is something with utf8, files are parsed, title is extracted, but result instead of russian words is (Ð¡ÐµÑ€Ð¸Ð°Ð»Ñ‹ Ð¢Ð£Ð¢! Ð¡ÐµÑ€Ð¸Ð) unknown symbols

i use

```
$cont = "dasdas<title>Сериалы ТУТ! Сериалы онлайн sda</title>";
preg_match("'<title[^>]*?>(.*)</title>'siU", $cont, $match);

//$match[1] = Ð¡ÐµÑ€Ð¸Ð°Ð»Ñ‹ Ð¢Ð£Ð¢! Ð¡ÐµÑ€Ð¸Ð sda
```

when i try to add pattern modifier /u there is no changes, the same unknown matrix words. Please.

Maybe there is something with PHP?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://eval.in/139968). Are you testing this in a plain (fresh) php file?

Comment: This gives expected output on my end.

Comment: @HamZa , yes when i tried to reproduce on online parsers, everything work smoothly, but in google no info about, its why i think issue may be not in preg_match but on another level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a php or a regex problem, but an html problem. To obtain a correct display, you must add `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` in the header of your html code.

As an aside comment: using the U modifier is useless:

```
preg_match('~<title[^>]*>(.*?)</title>~si', $cont, $match);
```